# MySQL on empty DB with no FKs can't create table: Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint

Tags: mysql

I dropped all tables in a db but had to use `foreign_key_checks=0` because of a table referencing the other not being deleted.

Now I enabled foreign key checks and I can't create `users` table in an empty database. I feel like there is a hanging FK constraint. I dropped the DB and re-created, same result.

```
[HY000][1822] Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'apiCalls_users_Id_fk' in the referenced table 'users'
```

```sql
set foreign_key_checks=0; --with or without this, same thing.
CREATE TABLE users (
    id integer NOT NULL,
);
```

This is literally what I am trying to create in an **empty database** that has no tables, that was dropped and re-created with `create schema`. 
It fails with just 1 column. If I try this in a schema `some_other_schema_name` it works.

Also restarted MySQL couple of times, no change.
`mysql  Ver 8.0.15 for osx10.14 on x86_64 (Homebrew)`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There was another constraint in another database(!) (another schema!) referencing the constraint in this database. (Which was wrongly created by an ORM automatically)

I've found out this by looking into `information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE` and running query `CONSTRAINT_NAME LIKE '%apiCalls%'` to find what was referencing...

Interesting.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. It is indeed caused by a constraint placed in another Database and refers to the different database and table name of the table you attempt to create.

Having found the name of the constraint that prevents the creation of your particular table (outputed in the #1822 error), you need to find the database it is coming from (see the above Seregwethrin's post).

Then you need to delete (or edit) the contstraint.

```
ALTER TABLE `different_table_name`
DROP FOREIGN KEY `id_name_fk`;
```

Note that in my case I got an error in my attampt to delete the constraint and I needed to completely remove the associated index fisrt.

```
ALTER TABLE `different_table_name` 
DROP INDEX  `id_name_fk`;
```

---